# Exchanging objects between C# and C++

Tags: c#, .net, c++, xml, serialization

Imagine a project with a C# component and a C++ component.  The C++ component is the old-school non .Net stuff (VC++ 6.0).  What is an easy way to transfer objects between the two components?  I'm tempted to use System.Xml.XmlSerializer, but I'm not sure how to start getting at the .Net libraries with this old VC++ app.

Maybe there's an even easier way that I haven't considered.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at C++/CLI. You can write a wrapper with it that translates between both worlds.

Comment: Far better then using COM, IMHO.

Comment: @gimpf, seconded. COM simply sucks.

Answer (score 4):

How do you feel about using COM? .NET applications can both consume COM objects and can expose themselves as COM objects.

Comment: COM is incredibly complex AND it is incredibly slow. Unless the original C++ project already exposes a COM interface, using C++/CLI as glue between native C++ and .NET assemblies is a better alternative.

Comment: @Eduardo: "COM is incredibly complex" is not a useful remark. Would the OP need to use all of the complexity, some of it, or more likely almost none of it?

Comment: @John Saunders: Any non-trivial subset of COM is incredibly complex. Even trivial subsets of it are.

Comment: @Eduardo: you clearly don't know what you're talking about. Do you not know how easy it is to create a COM object in .NET? About as easy as it is to create one using VB6.

Comment: @John Saunders: It is as easy as useless. If you are going to create your components in .NET, why not create the applications that will consume them in .NET as well? The more usual case is that you want to consume a legacy COM component from a .NET application, not the other way around.

Comment: @Eduardo: Occasionally, it's necessary it's necessary to use code which is not written in .NET. That's what the OP is asking about. It also comes into play when dealing with things like Classic ASP pages, VBSCRIPT or other scripting environments that understand COM but don't understand .NET, etc. Another example is Microsoft Office products. I can't rewrite those in .NET.

Answer (score 2):

Make the C++ a COM Object ?

Answer (score 0):

If your C++ component is an unmanaged DLL exporting C-style functions ["Platform Invoke"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26thfadc.aspx) is another option. This technic allows access from .NET (C#) managed code to the unmanaged C++ code but not in the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

Depending how large your project is, I would recompile the VC6 stuff as C++/CLI with VS 2008.  Then you can access the .net stuff directly.